# Creating a website to convert text into Json file

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, json

I am trying to make a website for users to type information about themselves and eventually generate a Json file for them to download. I was able to create this using Java but I need some help turning this into a website for users to use.

Also, if there is any way I can do this using just JS, HTML and CSS.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.json.simple.*;

public class JsonFile {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter ID: ");
        int id_Input = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter First Name: ");
        String firstname_Input = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Last Name: ");
        String lastname_Input = scan.next();

        JSONObject patient = new JSONObject();
        patient.put("id", id_Input);
        patient.put("firstName", firstname_Input);
        patient.put("lastName", lastname_Input);

        System.out.println("Enter Father's First Name: ");
        String firstname_father = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Father's Last Name: ");
        String lastname_father = scan.next();

        JSONObject father = new JSONObject();
        father.put("firstName", firstname_father);
        father.put("lastName", lastname_father);

        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
        list.add(patient);
        list.add(father);

        try(FileWriter file = new FileWriter("testJSON.json")) {
            file.write(list.toString());
            file.flush();
        }
       catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you take user input with `<input>` tags and assign their values to values.
Then make an object in `JS`
Ex: `var jsonObj = {}; jsonObj.name = nameVar; jsonObj.age = ageVar;`
etc.
Then using `JSON.stringify(jsonObj)`, it will be converted to a string which you can then make a file for them to download.

The reason I'm not putting this in an official answer is because I don't have time to test it myself right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a file in memory for user to download, not through server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my understanding you need to convert JSON based on user input. Use my below example code. May be it will help you.

```
   <html>
<input type="text" id="txtid" value="Enter id"/>
<input type="text" id="txtfirstname" value="Enter first name"/>
<input type="text" id="txtlastname" value="Enter last name"/>
<input type="button" value="Display" id="btnDisplay" onclick="output()"/>

    <script>
        function output(){
            //Data collector
            var oData=[];
            //Local Data object initialization 
            var local={
                id:document.getElementById("txtid").value,
                firstname:document.getElementById("txtfirstname").value,
                lastname:document.getElementById("txtlastname").value
            };
            //Push data in data collector
            oData.push(local);
            //Convert data in json format string
            var output=JSON.stringify(oData).toString();
            //Data output
           document.write("<h1>"+ output +"</h1>")

           download("testfile.txt",output)
        }

        function download(filename, text) {
            var element = document.createElement('a');
            element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
            element.setAttribute('download', filename);
            element.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(element);
            element.click();
            document.body.removeChild(element);
        }

    </script>
</html>

//**Paste this code in HTML file and run**.

//This is simple example for your reference only.
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Abhishek Tomar
I will keep you updated as I work more on this project!
This code will definitely help me to get started :)

Comment: If this is helpful for you please accept my answers. Click on check in front of my post. Glad to help.

Comment: Just did ;) Thanks!